# Getting the File Path from a FileUpload dialog in ASP.NET throws FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm trying to implement a FileUpload tool to allow users to select an image to set as a Display Picture. I'm storing the images on Azure Database. However, my implementation keeps looking for the image in a different location on the harddisk and not the location specified by the dialog.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="imageUploader" runat="server" />
```

C# Code behind:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(imageUploader.PostedFile.FileName))
{
         blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

It gives me this Error:

[image]

The code tries to get the image from THIS location even though it is actually in the Sample Pictures in Documents. Why can't I specify the actual Path of the image to the System.IO.File.OpenRead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better learn ASP.NET before tagging with AZURE.

[FileName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) of the PostedFile refers to:

> Gets the fully qualified name of the file **on the client**.

What you need is the [InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property. And you can give it directly to the UploadFromStream:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(imageUploader.PostedFile.InputStream);
```